# ldap_modify_ext_s fails with error 11 while writing data to active directory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, ldap, msdn

I am using the Winldap API ldap_modify_ext_s to write data to the Active Directory. It writes successfully when the data is not too large. But when the data is really huge it fails with error 11. Error 11 maps to LDAP_ADMIN_LIMIT_EXCEEDED. What can be done to be able to successfully write data to the directory? Can some configuration be changed on the Active Directory? Like increase the maximum data limit for the attribute? Or Can some alternate API be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following msdn link on the Non linked multi value attribute size limits

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31919.active-directory-non-linked-multi-valued-attribute-size-limits.aspx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).